# How to simulate a piece of cloth with some rigid insets?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, cloth-simulation

I want to do a physics simulation of a piece of falling cloth that has some eyelets with metal rings, as in the stylized image below, with the cloth in blue and the metal ring in red.

[image]

The cloth should behave as, well, cloth, while the metal rings of the eyelets should behave as rigid objects, with the two moving around in a compatible way: the cloth doesn't go through the eyelet and they are attached together. How can this situation be simulated in blender?

Comment: @downvoter(s): I can improve the question, if you let me know what's unclear or what's wrong with it

Comment: I do agree. Folks are perfectly entitled to downvote, of course. But it's unhelpful to do so without explanation.

Comment: Actually I don't know what's wrong with the question, I totally understand what you are asking for. I'm just not sure how to solve it the best way... I have an idea, but it's far from perfect.

Comment: You need to create a pin group with the vertices around the hole, and parent the cloth to the ring object, then parent the cloth to the ring and when you'll move the ring the cloth will follow?

Comment: @moonboots That's what I'm trying to do (well, I used an empty as hook for the pin group and parented that to the ring), however the ring should be a rigid body object. Although this works, the rigid body simulation is not interacting with the cloth, so the ring can fall down and rotate etc. freely as if there was no cloth attached. And in the question it even says "some eyelets with metal rings", so more than one. Two or three or more rigid bodies might tumble in any kind of directions without being restricted by the size of the cloth... that's what my problem is with it.

Comment: Yes I'd like to have a cloth with many eyelets and metal rings so that when the cloth falls due to gravity, the rings are dragged together, like it would happen in real life if you were to drop a curtain with eyelets and metal rings. For the particular application I'm dealing with right now it'd be enough to have a way to ensure that the circular eyelets in the cloth stay circular through the cloth simulation, and I can add in the metal rings after the simulation (which is a bit more tedious but alright), I'm curios in general how to simulate a cloth with a rigid part attached to it though

Comment: maybe you should fake it, the rings could be parented to the vertices of the cloth and therefore that's the physic of the cloth that would make the rings fall

Comment: Got somehow  to get round circular dependency between Rigid Body and Cloth Simulations.. maybe parent eyelet, fake Boolean out the hole....

Comment: another way would be to bake the ring physic animation, then hook the cloth to them